# How to make 301 redirect for 1 parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls like this
site.com/certificate/?cert_id=6

and trying to convert it to friendly url like it

site.com/certificate/6/

For this I was trying to use following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^certificate/(.*)$ certificate?cert_id=$1 [QSA]
```

but it's doesn't work.

I'll be appreciate if anybody can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting 404 for `site.com/certificate/6/`? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: No, I get 200 from site.com/certificate/6/. .htaccess located in home directory (wordpress website).

Comment: One more moment: I have checking for get parameter: if (isset($_GET['cert_id'])){ "do something"}else {echo "error";}. So now I have code 200 and echo Error

Comment: If this is Wordpress then use WP rewrite API not these rules